# Handle smart contract transaction express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, solidity

I have been coding my small project but I'm facing a problem.
here is my code:

```
app.get('/thu', (req, res) => {
  thu(function(err, output){
    if(err){
      res.json({"err": ""+err, "output": output});
      return;
    }
    res.send("ket qua: ", output);
  });
});
var thu = function(callback){
  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress).then((txnCount) => {
    console.log("goi thu");
    var method = contract.methods.thu();
    var encodedABI = method.encodeABI();
    var thuTx = {
      from: senderAddress,
      to: contractAddress,
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txnCount),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(GAS_LIMIT),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(GAS_PRICE),
      data: encodedABI,
    };
    sendTxn(thuTx, callback);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("web3 err", err);
    callback(err, null);
  });
};

function sendTxn(rawTx, callback) {
  var privateKeyBuffer = new Buffer(privateKey, 'hex');
  var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
  transaction.sign(privateKeyBuffer);
  var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
  '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, txnHash) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("txn err", err);
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      console.log("txn result", txnHash);
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    callback(err, null);
  });
}
```

I'm sure that my smart contract runs ok. when I hit submit the code send a transaction to Rinkeby and it is ok. but I cannot receive any responses. 
Please help my solve my problems. thank you.

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but why does `thu` use a callback.  You can just return the promise you already have and let the caller use the promise.  There is never a need to wrap a promise in a plain callback like you are doing.

Comment: Your call to `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction()` looks wrong to me because you are BOTH passing a callback and using `.catch()` on the return.  Usually, the API would use promises or a callback, but not both at the same time.

Comment: thank you. problem solved. btw, how can I close this question? I'm just a new member.

Comment: yeb. I don't need callback here, tks. i'm trying to get output from the transaction.

Comment: You can either provide an answer yourself (it is OK to answer your own question) or you can delete your question.

Comment: ok thank you. I will do it right now

Answer (score 0):

`sendSignedTransaction` returns a Promise combined event emitter.

> Ethereum as a blockchain has different levels of finality and
>   therefore needs to return multiple “stages” of an action. To cope with
>   requirement we return a “promiEvent” for functions like
>   web3.eth.sendTransaction or contract methods. This “promiEvent” is a
>   promise combined with an event emitter to allow acting on different
>   stages of action on the blockchain, like a transaction.

You can place a console.log on every event, to see what is happening, or if you're getting an error.

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx)
    .once('transactionHash', hash => console.log(`Hash: ${hash}`)
    .once('receipt', receipt => console.log(`Receipt: ${receipt}`)
    .on('confirmation', (confNumber, receipt) => console.log(confNumber))
    .on('error', error => console.error(error))
    .then(receipt => {
        // will be fired once the receipt its mined
    });
```

Comment: honestly, I'm not a web developer and not familiar with it web development. but fortunately, I just discovered my problem. I forgot to put callback in else {};
anyway, thank you. I will learn more about events.

Comment: Glad you could make it work, we thought you weren't getting a response from the blockchain, not that your callback wasn't being called.

Comment: I can only get the transaction hash from the blockchain. unfortunately, it is not what I expected. I want to get the output, not the transaction hash. I'm still looking for a way to do it. thank you very much. but we cannot discuss further on how to get output since it is not related to the problems asked above.

Comment: Look at my provided answer, you will get much more than the transaction hash. The receipt, confirmations... You need to utilize the event emitter, not only the `sendSignedTransaction` callback.

Comment: sorry, but receipt doesn't contain output data.

Comment: What output exactly do you need? Because you may get that with another call, once you have the transaction hash.

Comment: for instance, function(){return "hello";}. I expect "hello"

Comment: I only want to get data from that function which I just submitted, can I just do that?

Comment: `sendTransaction` (and `signed`) will return the transaction hash, if you wish to get the return value of a function, you have to use `call`. Can you give me the link to the transaction on etherscan?

Comment: here 0x283c34360b3afb1925a77a4372b677de776b14f499405ce9b1c5b34559fce0ae

Comment: i deployed it in rinkeby

Comment: You won't be able to see the return value, what I recommend, is to implement an Event, and listen to that event with web3, and notify the return value using an event.

Comment: what event should I listen to?

Comment: You should create an event on your contract, and call it. Check: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html

Comment: after doing some researches, I see that people use events to handle it.  but I still wonder why remix-ide can get the output. 
remix-ide can show the output values, that mean there are some ways to get the output.

Comment: Yes, when calling the contract from another contract, you can get the value, but not from web3.

Comment: thank you. my friend told me that he could get the value from web3, that why I tried a lot to get it but later on he admitted not being able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Problems solved. the problem is I forgot the put the callback(...) in else {...}.